# insert a particular char into the string

Tags: c, string

for ex: if the string="EXAM"
insert a char'x' after every char of a string
output must be string="EXXXAXMX".i have done program for that but i stored a string and then i inserted 'x'.but i want the pgm to get input string from user and insert a char 'x' after every char of that string.how to do it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void strexpand(char [],char []);
void main()
{
  char name[]="EXAM";
  int length;
  clrscr();
  length=strlen(name);
  printf("\n\tName=%s Length=%d",name,length);
  strexpand(name);

  getch();
}
void strexpand(char name[])
{ 
  int i;
  while(name[i]!='\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
  if(name[i]=='\0')
  {
    name[8]=name[4];
    name[6]=name[3];
    name[4]=name[2];
    name[2]=name[1];
    name[1]='x';
    name[3]='x';
    name[5]='x';
    name[7]='x';
    printf("\n\n\tAltered string is=%s",name);
  }
}
```

Comment: no point checking for null character in your loop if you are writing to fixed indices. If your initial string IS 4 characters long, you cant just go writing beyond the end of it like that.

Comment: different prototype `void strexpand(char [],char []);`. too small size `char name[]="EXAM"`

Comment: Copy the string in to a new string where you inserting 'x' after each char .

Comment: Also, your code is broken even for the fixed string – not only do you discard the `const`-ness of a compile time string, you write nine bytes into a five-byte memory region.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this , the new string will be always 2 times bigger than the original , so we should allocate it as 2 times bigger string , and then just copy as i said on comments.

```
 char* strexpand(char name[]) 
 {
          int length=0;
          int i=0 ,j=0;
          char* retValue =null;


          while(name[length]!='\0')
          {
             length++;
          }
            length++;

          retValue = malloc (sizeof(char* length * 2));
          if(!retValue)
               return null;
         for(i=0;i<length;i++,j+=2)
         {
             retVal[j] = name[i];
             retVal[j+1] = 'x';
         }
         //at this point j did got +=2 
         retVal[j] = '\0';

         return retVal;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void strexpand(char []);
void main()
{
  char name[9];
  strcpy(name, "EXAM");
  int length;
  length=strlen(name);
  printf("\n\tName=%s Length=%d",name,length);
  strexpand(name);

  getch();
}
void strexpand(char name[])
{ 
  int i=0;
  while(name[i]!='\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
  if(name[i]=='\0')
  {
    name[7]=name[3];
    name[5]=name[2];
    name[3]=name[1];
    name[1]=name[0];
    name[0]='x';
    name[2]='x';
    name[4]='x';
    name[6]='x';
    name[8] = '\0';
    printf("\n\n\tAltered string is=%s",name);
  }
}
```

- note1: This code assumes that the string has at most has 8 characters.
- note2: Arrays are indexed from 0. The first element is `array[0]`
- note3: the line `name[8] = '\0';` takes care of closing the string since C strings are [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). It is important to know that to store `n` chars in a C string you always need `n+1` bytes.

### Some explanation

```
void strexpand(char name[])
{ 
  int i;
  while(name[i]!='\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
```

This part is problematic, becasue `i` will have some junk value. It should be

```
void strexpand(char name[])
{ 
  int i = 0;
  while(name[i]!='\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
```

Also when using strexpand you assue that its parameter has at least 9 elements because of this line:

```
name[8]
```

When you give it a smaller string than 9 elements (as in your code) the code will try to access elements outside of allocated space, which will result in a segfault.

So, when you called it with "EXAM" the parameter looked like this in memory:

```
['E','X','A','M','\0']
```

Given this, `name[5]` was already problematic.